# Scala Puzzle : Any ideas on how to make this work?

Tags: scala

This code doesn't work!

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a plus b
```

So, I tried defining `plus` like so:

```
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

But, the compiler still complains `Cannot resolve symbol plus`!

Any ideas?

Comment: Rough crowd. Good Scala n00b question, or so I thought. +1

Comment: Thanks! Although I've been using Scala for sometime, rarely have I used Implicit classes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a plus b` doesn't work because it is shorthand for `a.plus(b)` and there is no such method on `Int` in the standard library.  To make that work you have to "enhance" the `Int` class via implicit conversion.

```
implicit class MyPlus[T](a: T)(implicit ev:Numeric[T]) {
  def plus(b: T): T =  ev.plus(a,b)
}
```

Now you can do `3 plus 5` or `a plus b` etc.

You can also do it like this (a little more concise and readable but essentially the same thing):

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
implicit class MyPlus[T: Numeric](a: T) {
  def plus(b: T): T = a + b
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` inside `add` is an `Int`, and `scala.Int` doesn't have a `plus` method, we need to create an implicit conversion from `scala.Int` to something which wraps an `Int` and has a `plus` method:

```
implicit class IntWithPlus(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def plus(other: Int) = i + other
}
```

Now, everything just works:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a plus b

add(2, 3)
// => 5
```

An alternative would be to create a type `Int` that gets imported into the local namespace shadowing `scala.Int` and give that type a `plus` method.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!